# Spark structured streaming no console output on databrick

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to use structured streaming in databrick with socket as source, and console as the output sink.

However, I am not able to see any output on databrick.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

lines = (spark
  .readStream.format("socket")
  .option("host", "localhost")
  .option("port", 9999)
  .load())

countdf = lines.select(split(col("value"), "\\s").alias("word")).groupBy("word").count()

checkpointDir = "/tmp/streaming"
streamingQuery = (countdf
  .writeStream
  .format("console")
  .outputMode("complete")
  .trigger(processingTime="1 second")
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointDir)
  .start())
```

[image]

In another terminal, send data via socket

[image]

I am not able to see any updates/changes in the dashboard, and there is no output shown. When I try to show the countdf, it is showing `AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `.show` on the streaming queries. Also, in the case of the `console` output, it's printed into logs, not into the notebook. If you just want to see the results of your transformations, on Databricks you can use [`display` function](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/visualizations/index.html#display-function) that supports visualization of streaming datasets, including [settings for checkpoint location & trigger interval](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/visualizations/index.html#structured-streaming-dataframes).